# IOS AVAudioSession.setActive causes other apps audio to hang

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am writing a program that records audio. I would like to allow other applications, such as Rdio or the Music app, to continue playing in the background while the recording happens. I have been able to get this to work using the MixWithOthers and DuckOthers options. For example:

```
session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions:
     AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers, error:&error)
```

However, if another application is playing while I activate the session, the audio hangs for a moment. Is there a way to activate and de-activate the audio session without audio pausing or hanging momentarily?

The code i am using to activate the session is pretty basic:

```
if !session.setActive(true, error: &error) {
    println("could not make session active")
    if let e = error {
        println(e.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

I have verified that the audio is hanging when the session is activated by stepping through it with the debugger.